# How to do a period over period comparison in Amazon QuickSight?

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I want to compare data from the current period (e.g current month) with the previous period (e.g. last month).

Let's say I have the following dataset:

| date | orders |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 1 |
| 2020-01-02 | 2 |
| 2020-01-03 | 5 |
| 2020-02-01 | 4 |
| 2020-02-02 | 2 |

And I want to get:

| Jan 2020 Orders | Feb 2020 Orders | Delta Orders |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 6 | -25% |

---

Period can be selected by user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the way I reached your desired outcome is by creating a calculated filed "MoM Change":

```
percentDifference(sum({ orders}), [date ASC], -1, [])
```

[image]

Also, this tutorial might be helpful: https://learnquicksight.workshop.aws/en/business-level-up.html

Comment: This Quicksight *difference functions seems to break when in the Columns you have expandable granularities. Example: if you have the columns: date_year(YEAR), date_quarter(QUARTER) and date(MONTH), being date_year = date and date_quarter=date. Is there any way to overcome this limitation?

Answer (score 1):

I was hoping to upvote the example above as it helped me solve this problem.  I'm not yet to a reputation of 15 (how embarrassing) so I can't yet do that.  But thank you @chrigu for the help.

In researching this, I found that QuickSight has extended this with a few similar functions.  I used this one, which works with less parameters:

```
periodOverPeriodPercentDifference(measure, date, period, offset))
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/periodOverPeriodPercentDifference-function.html

There are several other variants for periodTo___ and periodOver___ to check out as well.

Comment: Here are the docs that were just released:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/add-comparative-and-cumulative-date-time-calculations-in-amazon-quicksight/